# how to add data from mongodb database to highchart-ng

Tags: angularjs, node.js, highcharts

[This is the highchart code in angular controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACZYq.png)

I am using charts for the first time in angularjs.I want to show data from my mongodb database like on x-axis all the names of tasks and on y-axis the total time required by that particular task to complete i.e- Total Duration.

I have added static data for the html to look like the attached image.
I am developing a project using **MEAN Stack**.I want to how know how do i add the data i get from database to highcharts.

This is how the output should look without statically giving data:
[image: This is how the output should look without statically giving data]

```
     var tasks = ['Task1','Task2','Task3' ]
     var res = [26,61,1]
      $scope.chartConfig = {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Task Duration'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: tasks,
            crosshair: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Task Duration (Hrs)'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span> 
            <table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0"> 
         {series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tasks',
            data: res
        }]
    }
```

Comment: u need to do a node controller  that fetches the data from and mongo database then you need in your controller to do ajax call to that the route of controller that return the chart data and then display put the data you received in variable tasks and res

Comment: in angular controller i made a ajax call function `function getData(){
            
            var receivedData; 
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "http://localhost:3000/api/client",
                async: false,
                success: function(data){
                    // alert('data'+data);
                    receivedData = data;
                    console.log(data)
                }
            }); 

       return receivedData; 
     }
     getData(); `

Comment: but when i call the Node api data return is success: false and no token provided